Как преобразовать список с удалением зеркальных элементов python
Нужно написать программу на Пайтон, которая будет искать из списка чисел 1-20, такие пары чисел, сумма которых является делителем введённого числа(от 3 до 20). Исключая элементы с одинаковым цифрами.
Например число 6, делители: 2(но его нельзя составить из разных цифр 1+1 нельзя), 3 (получаем пары 1и2,2и1, но в ответ нужно только первую, 6 пары 1и5, 2и4,4и2,5и1, тут опять есть зеркальные.
Я смог написать простенький код на нахождение всех возможных пар, теперь мне нужно либо убрать их, либо переписать код.
n = 11
n1 = int(n//2) 
vs1_ = list(range(1, n1)) 
vs_ = list(range(1, n)) 
o = [] 
for i in vs1_:
    for j in vs_:
        if i == j:
        continue
        else:
        sum_ = i + j
            if n % sum_ == 0:
                o1 = f'{i}{j}'
                o.append(o1)
            else:
            continue

print(o)


Что у вас считается дублями? Какой язык?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

@MBo думаю и так понятно - те, что зеркальные - тоже дубли...правда почему оставлять именно 15, а не 51 - не ясно (с другими аналогично)

Паскаль, нужно оставлять 15 потому что он получается первым. Нужно найти пары чисел от 1 до 20, которые в сумме являются делителями 6.

Мда, лучше не стало... Попробуйте всё-таки чётко сформулировать задачу, чтобы даже мы поняли.

Я просто перибрал все числа и он вывел мне такой список, а вот как дальше его обработать не понятно. Нужно что бы делитель был суммой не одних и тех же чисел. 1+2=3. 2+1=3 т.е. не уникальное значение

Добавьте язык в теги вопроса.

if i == j: -> if i >= j:

Каюсь, я прокололся с пониманием задачи - ну, извините, такой заголовок. Чего ж тут ещё можно понимать - дайте этот же список, но без дублей. Теперь и я не понимаю, чего собственно требуется. Просто для других читателей оставлю вариант на Python (задача на самом деле нужная), в котором удаляются дубликаты в списке:
import os
my_list = ['51', '12', '15', '21', 0.128, '12', '24', '42', '42', '51', 'Вася', 15]
unique_items = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
print(my_list)
print(unique_items)
os.system("pause")


И для примера в вопросе сработает так, как там написано?

Это неправильный ответ

Это просто удаление одинаковых, мне немного другое нужно

Вы можете внятно объяснить чего хочется? По какому принципу Вы формируете из одного списка другой? Ну, а я Вам помочь уже не смогу. Я видел подобный вопрос уже сегодня, его закрыли. Он был для Питон. С Паскалем я пас.
